# VBA Google Search Function - Not capturing all of the search criteria in "search cell"

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

I'm using the code below to create a google search function in excel. It works however, when the search criteria is more than one word, like Burger King, it only performs the search function on the first word which renders the results useless (ie. just burger) and the second word shows up in a seperate chrome tab. My code is below. I have some elements that aren't necessary that are leftover from me trying different ideas. Any thoughts?

```
Private Sub CommandButtonSearch_Click()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim googleChromePath As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim search_string As String


    Name = Range("B2")
    search_string = Replace(Name, "", "+")
    URL = "https://news.google.com/search?q="

    googleChromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

    Shell (googleChromePath & " -url https://news.google.com/search?q=" & Name)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
search_string = Replace(Name, "", "+") '<< this doesn't replace anything
```

should be

```
search_string = Replace(Name, " ", "+") '<< replace spaces
```

and

```
Shell (googleChromePath & " -url https://news.google.com/search?q=" & Name)
```

should be

```
Shell (googleChromePath & " -url https://news.google.com/search?q=" & search_string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm still getting the same error but now it shows the remaining words in separate google chrome tabs. Any thoughts?